# Why I cant defined name '$url'?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to use $url inside lodfromurl() function but I cant defined $url inside lodfromurl() ! can you help me please ?

Package Used flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer

The full code is :

```
import 'package:example/Home/booklist.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer/flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.dart';


class PDFViwer extends StatefulWidget {
   final String url;
  PDFViwer({Key key, @required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PDFViwerState createState() => _PDFViwerState();
}

class _PDFViwerState extends State<PDFViwer> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    lodfromurl();

  }
  PDFDocument document;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  lodfromurl()async{
     document = await PDFDocument.fromURL($url);
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url isn't defined in your state class so you have to use widget. to access variable.

```
import 'package:example/Home/booklist.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer/flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.dart';


class PDFViwer extends StatefulWidget {
   final String url;
  PDFViwer({Key key, @required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PDFViwerState createState() => _PDFViwerState();
}

class _PDFViwerState extends State<PDFViwer> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    lodfromurl();

  }
  PDFDocument document;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  lodfromurl()async{
     document = await PDFDocument.fromURL(widget.url);
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```